# Read jboss logger file (get absolute path)

Tags: java, logging, jboss

I'm using Jboss eap 6.2. I created second logger in my `standalone.xml` file

```
        <file-handler name="stats-handler">
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="stats.log"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </file-handler>
        <logger category="stats">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="stats-handler"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
```

Now I want read this file. I known it can be read as normal file, but how can I get path to this file? Maybe there is a special class to do this?

I'm writing to this logger this way:

```
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
...
private static final Logger stats = Logger.getLogger("stats");
....
    stats.info(log);
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this following code to get file log path using system property.

```
System.getProperty("jboss.server.log.dir");
```